# Audio maps of Spanish dialects?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación, recursos

Apart from vocabulary differences, the Spanish language has an enormous and fascinating diversity in pronunciation and accents. In my country (Argentina) people from the central inland region have a peculiar intonation ("tonada cordoooobesa" : they delay the stressed syllable by prolonging the previous vowel), that is very different from that of Buenos Aires; the north-west region has another "music", etc.  I'd like to learn to appreciate and distinguish them (and all Spanish-speaking regions) better. Does anyone know if there is some "Spanish dialect map" on the Internet, similar to [this one](http://aschmann.net/AmEng/#Au_Alaska) (American English) that allows one to hear the audio samples?

---

Aparte de las diferencias de vocabulario, el idioma español tiene una variedad enorme y fascinante de pronunciaciones y acentos. Sólo en mi país (Argentina), la gente del interior en el centro tiene una entonación particular ("tonada cordoooobesa": demoran la sílaba acentuada, prolongando la vocal anterior), que es muy diferente del habla porteña (Buenos Aires), como también de la del noroeste - que tiene otra "música", etc. Me gustaría aprender a gustar y distinguir mejor esas diferencias (en todo el ámbito de lengua española). Sabe alguien si existe algún "atlas auditivo de dialectos españoles" en Internet, similar a [este](http://aschmann.net/AmEng/#Au_Alaska) (inglés de EEUU) que permita escuchar ejemplos de habla regional?

Comment: No se si te refieres mas a lo que se conoce en Perú como `dejo`, por ejemplo, en la costa peruana hablamos diferente que en la sierra y la selva, es decir, a pesar de ser del mismo país y tener el mismo idioma tenemos diferentes `dejos`.

Comment: Si, se refiere a eso. Dejo, tonada, acento en este caso se usan indistintamente. Me parece que el uso de acento aquí viene del inglés accent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikilengua has this:

**[Atlas Oral](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Categor%C3%ADa%3aAtlas_oral)**

It's a website where people from all the word can upload their own recordings of short sentences indicating the accent they have. The site has different maps of countries or regions and over it you can see the recordings uploaded with the accent or the origin of the speaker. For example for Argentina is this **[one](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Atlas_oral/Argentina)**. So far, there isn't a great variety of files uploaded, but in most countries there is at least a few so they can be helpful. Anyways, any person can upload new files to make it more complete.

Answer (score 6):

I only found [Dialectoteca del Español](http://dialects.its.uiowa.edu/) (on the popup window click on "Factores geográficos"). It has some videos of native speakers from different regions.

But I think it's missing some dialects (for instance, there are no speakers from Argentina there).

---

Look for the "Audio clips" section on this [blog post](http://www.es-xchange.com/2008/03/21/seseo-ceceo-and-yeismo/) on *seseo, ceceo, yeísmo* - there are recording from various Spanish native speakers with a map showing where they are from.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few:

- [Localingual](https://localingual.com/)
- [Langscape](http://langscape.umd.edu/map.php)
- [Catálogo de voces hispánicas](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/voces_hispanicas/default.htm)
- [Voices of the Hispanic World](http://dialectos.osu.edu/)
- [Spanish in Texas Corpus](http://corpus.spanishintexas.org/en)
- [Sound Comparisons - Romance Languages](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Romance/map/eight/Lgs_All)

  - Iberia
  - Spanish: World
- Interactive Atlas of Spanish Intonation

  - [European Spanish](http://prosodia.upf.edu/atlasentonacion/mapa_e_english.html)
  - [American Spanish](http://prosodia.upf.edu/atlasentonacion/mapa_l_english.html)

Comment: https://forvo.com/languages/es/ ??